# Change git's proxy configuration for one push or pull

Tags: git, proxy

There's a proxy in my office so I've configured git to use that proxy and works fine. However, sometimes I work from home and I have to unset the proxy configuration, pull and push some commits, and set the proxy configuration again (witch I don't like at all because involves writing my password in the terminal).

Is there a way to change the proxy configuration just for one push or pull? I didn't find any mention of proxies in the [git-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) or [git-pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) manual pages.

It would also work for me a way to change the proxy configuration with an expiration date. Again, I didn't find anything in the [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) manual page.

---

This is what I usually do:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Some pulls and pushes.

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:port
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change/set any configuration value in the command line using [`git -c <name>=<value>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt). The problem is that you can **change** the value but not **unset** it.

Try `git -c http.proxy= pull` to set it to an empty string.